weird growth pattern of tree, grafting?
Whats the most likely explanation for following structure
2 Aesculus hippocastanum trees that merge into a third one, I guess its man made but what was the process?
Edit: Just found out about inosculation. Natural process by which trees merge mostly over their braches which after rubbing against eachother heal stuck together.


Probably grafted together but that sure does look weird.
